# Initializing NodeJS server example

Tags: node.js, webserver

I saw the next example [here](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener)

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
  console.log('server connected');
  c.on('end', function() {
    console.log('server disconnected');
  });
  c.write('hello\r\n');
  c.pipe(c);
});
server.listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

So `createServer()` has an anonymous function as a parameter. The way I see it this function listens and sends back whatever it receives, which is `c`.

Am I right so far? And where is `c` coming from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `c` variable is created inside the `net.createServer` function. `c` is returned through the callback given as parameter to the `createServer` function.

Example:

```
function createServer(callback) {
   var c = "hello world";
   callback(c);
}

createServer(function(c) {
   console.log(c); // Hello world
});
```

In your case, `c` is not a string of course. It was just for the example. It's another object: a socket.

Comment: Okay its clear now. The documentation doesn't say anything about it - unless I'm looking in the wrong place